# Confusion About Array and String in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

What is the difference between `S1`, `S2` and `S3`?

```
char S1[6];
S1[0] = 'A';
S1[1] = 'r';
S1[2] = 'r';
S1[3] = 'a';
S1[4] = 'y';

char S2[6] = {'A','r','r','a','y'};

string S3 = "Array";
```

When I run the program using `if (strcmp(a,b) == 0)`, where `a, b = S1, S2, S3`.
It shows that `S2` and `S3` are the same, and `S1` and `S2` is different. 
Why is this the case?? 
Why not all three are equivalent?

And when I add back `'\0'` to both `S1b`, `S1c`. All 3 are the same. This is understandable.

BUT why in my first trial, `S2` and `S3` are the same then?? I did not include `'\0'` too. And I suspect `S1` and `S2` should be the same, but not `S2` and `S3`.

Can anyone tell me why my thought is wrong???

Thanks for your answers. I have tried and changed the settings to the followings:

```
char S1[5];
S1[0] = 'A';
S1[1] = 'r';
S1[2] = 'r';
S1[3] = 'a';
S1[4] = 'y';

char S2[5] = {'A','r','r','a','y'};

string S3 = "Array";
```

And now clearly `S2` and `S3` are not the same, since they differs by a `'\0'`. 
However, I am still a bit confused why `S1` and `S2` are not the same this time again if I use strcmp to compare the two?

Comment: `string` is not a standard C type

Comment: `S1[5]` is uninitialized; it might happen to contain `'\0'`. `S2[5] == '\0'`, because when an object is initialized (distinct from assignment), any elements not specified are set to zero.

Comment: strcmp depends on a \0 byte to decide where to stop comparing, that's why s1 and s2 aren't the same for that function: it's comparing potentially much more bytes with random data.

Comment: Did you define the name `string` as a typedef?

Comment: of course... 
indeed I am using it all the time and call a .h header to use string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the actual in-memory values of the arrays:

1. S1 is 6 elements big, yet you only specify values for 0-5, the 6th element is not explicitly set, so it retains whatever value the memory location had prior to allocation.
2. S2 is similar to S1 , only 5 elements are provided, however when using the `{,}` syntax any extra elements are zeroed. So `char foo[5] = { 1, 2 }` is identical to `char foo[5] = { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0}`.
3. S3 uses the string syntax way of initialising an array, which creates an array of `char` (or `wchar_t`) with an extra element set to `\0` (the null terminator).

Visually:

```
S1 = 0x41, 0x72, 0x72, 0x61, 0x79, 0x??
S2 = 0x41, 0x72, 0x72, 0x61, 0x79, 0x00
S3 = 0x41, 0x72, 0x72, 0x61, 0x79, 0x00
```

Note that you're running into a safety problem with `strcmp`: it doesn't have a length parameter, it keeps on searching until it encounters `\0`, which might be never (i.e. until it causes a segfault or access violation). Instead use a safer function like `strncmp` or (if using C++) the `std::string` type.

Comment: Up for explaining that {} initializes all extra elements to 0, which is why S2 contains the \0, while S1 doesn't

Answer (score 2):

`It shows that S2 and S3 are the same, and S1 and S2 is different.`

S3 contains the nul terminator which S1 does not have. This `string S3 = "Array";` means

```
| A | r | r | a | y | \0 |
```

While S2 is

```
| A | r | r | a | y | \0 |
```

While S1 is

```
| A | r | r | a | y | Garbage |
```

S1 and S2 comparison can lead to UB (i presume) because S1 is not nul-terminated and there is no length which we pass in `strcmp`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char S1[6];
    S1[0] = 'A';
    S1[1] = 'r';
    S1[2] = 'r';
    S1[3] = 'a';
    S1[4] = 'y';
    S1[5] = 0;

    char S2[6] = {'A','r','r','a','y', 0};
    printf("%d" ,strcmp(S1,S2));
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
0
```

Comment: So why S1 and S2 is different?

Comment: I know that S3 contains null terminator, and S2 does not. 
SO why they are the same?
While S1 and S2 both do not have null terminator, why are they different?

Comment: @CHANist - S2 contains the nul-terminator S1 does not

Answer (score 1):

strcmp() function starts comparing the first character of each string. If they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs until the characters differ or until a terminating null-character is reached.

I don't think it is safe to compare S1 and S2 using this. Input to strcmp is the address of first character. S1 is not null-terminated. Though 6 bytes are allocated in both cases, S1[5] is not initialised. Chances are that they have some garbage value. The risk here is that strcmp will end up comparing un-allocated memory also, in the search for character diff or null character. This can even lead to seg fault or access violation.

Visualising memory alignment of S1,S2,S3 might be something like this

```
S1 = A | r | r | a | y | ?
S2 = A | r | r | a | y | 0
S3 = A | r | r | a | y | 0
```

Any comparison between S2 and S3 is safe. S1 vs S2 or S3 might not be.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the existing answers

```
char S2[6] = {'A','r','r','a','y'};

string S3 = "Array";
```

Both are NULL terminated and hence `strcmp()` works well and says that they both are same. While for `S1` the assignment is done explicitly there is no NULL termination for this array. So this is not a valid string in C. So using `strcmp()` might lead to undefined behavior.

The point with `S3` is that S3 is a string literal which is read-only. Mostly these sort of values are stored in read-only locations. So when you try to write something to `S3` after initialization you might see a crash.So we should keep this in mind while using assignments like `S3`